# MVC - request-based data sharing fails, session based data sharing succeeds

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

My jsp page can access a bean with the following:

```
<jsp:useBean id="myBean" 
   type="myPackage.beans.MyBean" 
   scope="session" />
```

If I change the scope to "request" tomcat throws an exception: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.InstantiationException: bean myBean not found within scope

But I access my jsp page by forwarding from a servlet as follows:

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/MyJsp.jsp"); dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

I thought that the above forward would result in MyJsp.jsp inheriting the original servlet's  request object, so myBean should be available (its created and then stored using session.setAttribute("myBean", myBean) in the original servlet).  Is this not correct - why does the request scope fail while the session scope request succeeds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this not correct - why does the request scope fail while the
>   session scope request succeeds?

NO you are not correct.

Request object will be available only for the current request and there is no communication between `request` and `session` objects

To make your object available in the request , you should use

`request.setAttribute("OBJname" , Object)` before dispatching to your view

Comment: Thanks San Krish - obvious now that you point it out, but somehow I was overlooking this.